# It is okay to say 'heartfelt congratulations'?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, collocations

Can I say 'heartfelt congratulations' when deeply moved with joy by someone's success?

Comment: One may feel strongly about congratulations being offered; even if it is only a conventional form of words, there is plenty of precedent, e.g. "Ambassador Kelly C. Degnan offers heartfelt congratulations to the people of Georgia on the 102nd anniversary of Georgian Independence"

Comment: And... "Dear President-elect Trump, I would like to extend my heartfelt congratulations on your election as the next President of the United States of America.  As a very successful businessman with extraordinary talents, not only have you made a great contribution to the growth of the US economy, but now as a strong leader, you have demonstrated your determination to lead the United States. " (Shinzo Abe, Prime Minister of Japan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You are congratulating them, and you feel a desire to congratulate them from deep in your heart. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to say.